# Plotly Scatter Matrix with Trendline

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

Is there any way to plot a scatter matrix with trendlines in all of the graphs in python with plotly?

For instance:

[image]

I want to add a trendline for each trace in all the graphs.

Thank you!

Comment: i think an [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help

Comment: `fig = px.scatter_matrix(dataset_final_numerico, 
                        dimensions = list(dataset_final_numerico.columns)[1:-1], 
                        color = list(dataset_final_numerico.columns)[0],
                        color_discrete_sequence = ['#20a483', '#ff774a'],
                       )

# Atualizando o layout geral
fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor = "#FFFFFF", plot_bgcolor = "#ffebe3", width = 1800, height = 1800, colorway = ["#ff774a"], showlegend = True, title = "Matriz de Distribuição")
fig.update_traces(opacity = 0.75)
fig.show()`

Comment: I don't know if this can be addressed since no data is presented, but try the following. `df = px.data.tips();fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", color="smoker", trendline='ols', facet_col="sex", facet_row="time");fig.show()`